# Python was not found

Tags: python, debugging, module, package

Could anyone please help with fixing the following error when trying to run "!python3 -m pip install pywifi"?

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

-Add your python installation to your PATH so you dont have to specify a direct path to the executable
->Install Python again and tick the "add to path option" or add it manually